# for form validation is there any other methods than Regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript

can anyone tell methods of form validation other than regex in javascript also can anyone suggest any alternate methods without Regex for this following code?

```
           function AllowAlphabet(){
           if (!frm.alphabet.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/) && frm.alphabet.value !="")
           {
                frm.alphabet.value="";


                alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
           }
           if(frm.alphabet.value.length > 5)
           alert("max length exceeded");
```

Comment: i use validate.js, check here http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/

Comment: What's wrong with Regex?

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
var keyCode = window.event.keyCode || event.which;
if ((keyCode < 65 || keyCode > 90) && (keyCode < 97 || keyCode > 123) ) {
     alert("only letters allowed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with RegEx if I'm honest, however since you're asking, maybe you can do something like this:

```
var isValid = function (input) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var c = input.charAt(i);
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(c))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/SVy3R/1/

I'd like to note that I'm not sure what the performance here is, also I haven't tested it for various corner cases, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this function allow only alphabets in textbox

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
        try {
            if (window.event){
                var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e) {
                var charCode = e.which;
            }
            else { return true; }

            if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.Description);
        }
    }
    </script>
<input type="text" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event,this);" />
```

Comment: i'm a beginner so can you explain the above code? it wil be helpful

Comment: hello ashok put this script in your head section in your file and onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event,this);" use this function on which you want only alphabate. this function allow only alphabate and restrict pther letters